# issue with code=H10 error when deploying strapi with heroku

Tags: heroku, strapi

I am trying to deploy a strapi app to heroku and followed all the instructions in https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/deployment.html#heroku to the letter but the end results is an application error. can anyone please tell me where I am wrong :/

```
    2020-04-09T14:17:07.788133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=strapi-kisho.herokuapp.com request_id=5ecab12a-5c4b-4276-b277-71aea1655129 fwd="46.227.240.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2020-04-09T14:17:09.128795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=strapi-kisho.herokuapp.com request_id=170ffef2-e307-4a5d-82b8-d4d29a197a2c fwd="46.227.240.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 

bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-09T14:17:21.011324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/admin" host=strapi-kisho.herokuapp.com request_id=a6834f30-c180-427f-a926-ba9570548c38 fwd="46.227.240.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-09T14:17:22.086307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=strapi-kisho.herokuapp.com request_id=d7855a00-aa16-4c6a-bc08-af1986dd0c38 fwd="46.227.240.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: nah mate, I gave up on this after a while. I will be coming back to this in a couple of days when I'm working with gatsby JS. If you find a solution, pls let me know

Comment: I did a cache clear and it worked but then after another push I got the same herror. I even started a new project, push it, and still got the same error. Clearing cache worked for me once but that it.